# An optimal way to calculate the subset of a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, linear-algebra

Okay, so I'm implementing an algorithm that calculates the determinant of a `3x3` matrix give by the following placements:

```
A = [0,0 0,1 0,2 
     1,0 1,1 1,2 
     2,0 2,1 2,2]
```

Currently, the algorithm is like so:

```
float a1 = A[0][0]; 
float calula1 = (A[1][1] * A[2][2]) - (A[2][1] * A[1][2])
```

Then we move over to the next column, so it would be be:

```
float a2 = A[0][1];
float calcula2 = (A[1][0] * A[2][2]) - (A[2][0] * A[1][2]);
```

Like so, moving across one more. Now, this, personally is not very efficient and I've already implemented a function that can calculate the determinant of a `2x2` matrix which, is basically what I'm doing for each of these calculations.

My question is therefore, is there an optimal way that I can do this? I've thought about the idea of having a function, that invokes a template (X, Y) which denotes the start and ending positions of the particular block of the `3x3` matrix:

```
template<typename X, Y> 
float det(std::vector<Vector> data)
{
   //....

}
```

But, I have no idea if this was the way to do this, how I would be able to access the different elements of this like the proposed approach?

Comment: Am I reading this correctly, you're asking for a smooth way to do the "cross out line and column from matrix" that is done when developing a determinant?

Comment: You probably want to make your own iterators that skip the appropriate rows or columns. In any case, it's hard to be more efficient (on a performance standpoint) than hardcoding it for a 3x3 since that'll easily fit in cache and avoid any wasted operations.

Comment: @G.Bach Yes, basically. It sounds really easy.. Am I totally over complicating this?

Comment: Well, you could generate a copy of your matrix and remove the required entries from the copy. Deleting the line would be deleting the vector holding the contents of the line from the copy, and deleting the column would be deleting the respective entry in each remaining line - or better yet, do all that in passing while you copy the matrix. It can be written pretty elegantly, but I don't know what the most efficient way to calculate a determinant is. If you are exclusively doing 3x3 matrices, you could hardcode the [rule of Sarrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

Comment: @G.Bach That I could. It wouldn't be efficient to pass in 4 values, I just need to skip a row each time. I'm going to have a look. BUT in the worse case, this algorithm will always work on a `3x3` matrix, so hard coding it might not be the worst thing in the world would it?

Comment: I posted an answer, I'm not really sure how you would need to pass 4 values.

Comment: Perhaps you should write a program to generate the code that does the computation? That saves the tedium of writing it out all by hand, avoids introducing any extra copying, and may avoid mistakes creeping in.

Comment: @AlanStokes When I read this four weeks ago, I wasn't sure whether you're joking or not; were you?

Comment: @G. Bach Not in the slightest. Code generation is a very powerful technique. Doing all the logic once at build time means at execution time you only have to do the necessary computation, with minimal overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hardcode the [rule of Sarrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) like so if you're exclusively dealing with 3 x 3 matrices.

```
float det_3_x_3(float** A) {
    return A[0][0]*A[1][1]*A[2][2] + A[0][1]*A[1][2]*A[2][0]
           + A[0][2]*A[1][0]*A[2][1] - A[2][0]*A[1][1]*A[0][2]
           - A[2][1]*A[1][2]*A[0][0] - A[2][2]*A[1][0]*A[0][1];
}
```

If you want to save 3 multiplications, you can go

```
float det_3_x_3(float** A) {
    return A[0][0] * (A[1][1]*A[2][2] - A[2][1]*A[1][2])
           + A[0][1] * (A[1][2]*A[2][0] - A[2][2]*A[1][0])
           + A[0][2] * (A[1][0]*A[2][1] - A[2][0]*A[1][1]);
}
```

I expect this second function is pretty close to what you have already.

Since you need all those numbers to calculate the determinant and thus have to access each of them at least once, I doubt there's anything faster than this. Determinants aren't exactly pretty, computationally. [Faster algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation) than the brute force approach (which the rule of Sarrus basically is) require you to transform the matrix first, and that'll eat more time for 3 x 3 matrices than just doing the above would. Hardcoding the [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) - which is all that the rule of Sarrus amounts to - is not pretty, but I expect it's the fastest way to go if you don't have to do any determinants for n > 3.

Comment: it would be nice with valid C++ code also (e.g. not `float[][] A`)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm not really used to C++, I hoped it was valid that way; I think it is now.